# Jasmine spyOn fails after moving to Webpack4

Tags: jasmine, webpack-4, spyon

Recently I'm migrating a project from `webpack` 3 -> 4. There's an issue wit `karma/jasmine` tests. In my test I want to import a TypeScript  namespace object and mock it.

```
spyOn(AlertDialogModule, 'createAlertDialog')
    .and.returnValue(
        Promise.resolve(alertDialogMock)
    );
```

But I have an error

> Error:  : createAlertDialog is not declared writable or has no
>   setter

I think, the reason is in how WP4 handles harmony exports

```
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
```